# Trouble with using a form to search multiple dates in Access and return a query

Tags: ms-access

So I've got a customer that has the need to search multiple dates on an appointment. I've created a form that has inputs set up to capture one of the dates and returns a query based on the dates entered.

**This is the table design:**

[image: TableDesign]

**This is what the form looks like**

[image: FormDesign]

**Submitting the form runs this query**

```
    SELECT PersonType.Category, Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, Person.DOB, Pet.Name, Pet.Microchip, Appointment.Cost, Appointment.AppointmentDate, Appointment.[Respite In], Appointment.[Respite Out], Appointment.[Rehome In], Appointment.[Rehome Out], Appointment.[In Date], Appointment.[Out Date], Appointment.[Service Location], Appointment.Note
FROM ((PersonType 
INNER JOIN Person ON PersonType.PersonTypeId = Person.PersonTypeID) INNER JOIN Pet ON Person.PersonID = Pet.PersonID) 
INNER JOIN Appointment ON (Pet.ID = Appointment.PetID) AND (Person.PersonID = Appointment.PersonID)
WHERE (((Appointment.AppointmentDate)>=[Forms]![Search Appointment Dates]![AppointmentDate] And (Appointment.AppointmentDate)<=[Forms]![Search Appointment Dates]![AppointmentEnd]) OR ((Appointment.[Respite In]) = [Forms]![Search Appointment Dates]![RespiteIn]) OR ((Appointment.[Respite Out]) = [Forms]![Search Appointment Dates]![RespiteOut]) OR ((Appointment.[Rehome In]) = [Forms]![Search Appointment Dates]![RehomeIn]) OR ((Appointment.[Rehome Out]) = [Forms]![Search Appointment Dates]![RehomeOut]) OR ((Appointment.[In Date]) = [Forms]![Search Appointment Dates]![InDate]) OR ((Appointment.[Out Date]) = [Forms]![Search Appointment Dates]![OutDate]));
```

Running the query from the form results in a 3270 error and attempting to open the query itself brings up the following error. To this point this has been more frustrating than I anticipated and I'm not sure why this is happening or how to get this to work successfully.

[image: Error]

Comment: first add the PersonType to the table design.  Also when you have the time I suggest replacing references to the form parameters with a function you can pass the parameters to.  Form Parameters are brittle and harder to troubleshoot.

Comment: I don't use dynamic queries. I prefer VBA to conditionally build filter criteria and apply to form or report. http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. All controls are referenced in query but not all have input which means Null is passed as parameter to query - although that should not itself cause error message, won't get desired output.

Comment: Possibly don't really need PersonID in Appointment - PersonID can be retrieved through Pet table. I tested query without WHERE clause and it opens. However, there are too many links. It joins Person to both Pet and Appointment and Pet also to Appointment - it's circular.

Comment: What June7th said + I don't know how you managed to get Name to work in the pet table.  Change to PetName and maybe that will help.  I couldn't reproduce the problem so please take a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Name is a reserved word; however, it does work in query. But beware, using reserved words as names can cause issue. Advise not to use reserved words as names, also not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters.